# midway x and y coordinates of an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, resolution, screen-orientation

I am trying to locate where a tap is located on the app view.
Some people I have asked say its 160 for the x, but they don't know about the y.

For now i just need the x but knowing the y doesn't hurt to know.

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

      CGPoint aPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view]; //locates x cords of touch

      if (aPoint.x <160){                                      //touches left side
        Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Person1.png"];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self                 
        selector:@selector(changeImageleft) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
    if (aPoint.x >=160){                                      //touches right side        
        Player2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Person1.png"];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self
        selector:@selector(changeImageright) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
       }
    }
```

This is what i have to differentiate between the left and right side of the view.

Comment: `aPoint` is the location within the view, not the screen.

Comment: Sorry, still new the the whole descriptions thing. I changed it to view now.thanks but i still need to location.

Comment: Or you could use the dimensions of UIView instead of UIScreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not hardcode the dimensions of the devices into your code, something android developers have to struggle a lot more. The width is the same for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5, but the height is different. Also all what happens when the orientation changes?

You should instead request the dimensions by code, here the code to get the two middle points:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{ 
  CGFloat midX = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) / 2.0f; 
  CGFloat midY = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) / 2.0f; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking this but how does this code work exactly? I am confused as to how it finds the midpoint or whatever if finds.

Comment: It reads out the dimensions of your UIView which then can be used to calculate the midpoints.

Comment: I edited my post to show how you can calculate both middle points.

Comment: Also there is a bit more convenient function to get mid points; `CGRectGetMidX()` & `CGRectGetMidY()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint aPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view]; //locates x cords of touch
    CGFloat midX = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f;
    SEL sel;

    if (aPoint.x < midX) {  //touches left side
      sel = @selector(changeImageleft);
    }
    else {  //touches right side        
      sel = @selector(changeImageright);
    }

    Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Person1.png"];
    [self performSelector:sel
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:0.25];
  }
```